# What is an example of Gâteaux differentiable but not Fréchet differentiable at a point in a finite-dimensional space?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples, gateaux-derivative

Let $V,W$ be nonzero normed spaces over $\mathbb{K}$ such that $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Let $E$ open in $\mathbb{K}$ and $p\in E$.

Let $f:E\rightarrow W$ be Gâteaux-differentiable at $p$.

Is $f$ necessarily Fréchet-differentiable at $p$ in this case?

I think this is not true in general, but cannot find a counterexample. What would be a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This counterexample comes from the Wikipedia page for [Frechet Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative)

Consider the function $f$ that is $0$ at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ and
$$f(x, y) = \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$$
otherwise.

Its Gateaux derivative $g$ as a function of the "direction" $h \in \mathbb{R}^2$ at $(0, 0)$ is $0$ if $h = (0, 0)$ and
$$g(h_1, h_2) = \frac{h_1^3}{h_1^2 + h_2^2}$$
otherwise.

Since this is not a linear function of $h$, the function $f$ has no Frechet derivative.

Comment: I can't understand at $h=(0,0)$, $f$ is Gateaux differentiable, $g=0$ is linear , continuos , why $f$ is not Frechet differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Chloe.Sannon    $g(h_1, h_2)$ is not linear.  Yes it is zero at $(0,0)$ but otherwise it varies non-linearly with $h_1$ and $h_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$
f(u,v)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\hbox{if $v=u^2$ and $(u,v) \neq (0,0)$} \\
0 &\hbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to check that the Gateaux derivative at $(0,0)$ exists, but $f$ is not even continuous.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong: $f(t,0)=0$. Indeed $f$ is constant on any straight line thru the origin.

Comment: Yes, now you are right. I always forget to exclude the origin from the first case.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
$\frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}$ if $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$
and $0$ otherwise

Comment: More details are in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4484963)